# How to read inputs from ember-easy-form in controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-easy-form

This is pretty simple, how can I access the input values from ember-easy-form inputs in my controller?

Comment: What have u tried? From reading their docs, u just pass in a controller property and that property just updates due to data binding.

Comment: `this.get('email')` and `this.getProperties('email')` neither of these worked

Comment: I think easy `ember-easy-form` assigns values directly to model that you pass to form `{{#form-for model}}`, so you should be able to get property like this.get(`model.email`) in your controller/parent component

Comment: I ended up using plain inputs.